# Null pointer exception using bindings in Clojure macro

Tags: clojure

I'm getting a Null Pointer Exception while in executing a macro to do some Java interop, and I can't figure out why.

I'm setting the fields of a Java object using a map with nested data, and since the names of the map keys are the same as the field names of the object, I created a macro:

```lisp
(defmacro set-keys! [pose m k klst]
  `(set! (. ~pose ~(symbol (name k)))
         (double-array (map #(% (~(keyword (name k)) ~m)) ~klst))))
```

For testing, I defined `pse` to be an initialized Java object with the fields of interest set to zero, and I defined `mp` as a simplified map that would still work:

```lisp
(def mp {:pos {:x 1 :y 2})
```

Now comes the odd behavior.  Executing `set-keys!` with explicitly typed arguments works:

```lisp
user> (set-keys! pse mp :pos [:x :y])
#<double[] [D@691ba57a>
```

But if I use run the code in a inside a `let` call:

```lisp
user> (let [x :pos y [:x :y]]
        (set-keys! pse mp x y))
```

I get a Null Pointer Exception with "No message." as the message.  What is the issue here?

EDIT: I defined `pse` with `(def pse (pose_t.))`, `pose_t` is a generated class, and the `pose_t()` constructor initializes all the arrays in its fields, but doesn't initialize the values.  The relevant lines of the class code for the simplified example are:

```java
public double pos[];

public pose_t() {
    pos = new double[3];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Macro arguments are not evaluated, so `~(keyword (name k))` expands to - roughly - `(keyword (name (quote x)))` - which is :x, not :pos

At least I guess that's the problem. If not, it would be nice if you could include a definition for `pse`.

Addendum: you can inspect what the macro is actually expanding to by evaluating:

```
user> (macroexpand-1 '(set-keys! pse mp x y))
(set! (. pse x) (clojure.core/double-array (clojure.core/map
    (fn* [p1__2066__2067__auto__] (p1__2066__2067__auto__ (:x mp))) y)))
```

Note the :x

Addendum 2: `(. obj field)` actually also doesn't evaluate `field`, meaning you'd have to use java reflection to make the field argument dynamic.

Comment: You're right, that is the issue.  For that part I can change `~(keyword (name k))` to be simply `~k`, but then I'll have the same issue with `~(symbol (name k))` expanding to `x` instead of `pos`.  Why doesn't the unquote force `x` to evaluate? Is is because macro-expansion happens before runtime?  If so, how can I programmatically send the arguments to the macro?  I'm ultimately going to have to call `map` on a collection with `set-keys!` inside the function passed to map.

Comment: Yes, it's because macros manipulate *code* - not values. The unquote doesn't evaluate, it inserts the literal expression (piece of code) that's given as the argument. As far as I can tell you can more clearly write the functionality you need using plain functions and java reflection or a fixed mapping of keywords to field assignment functions. That is, if you really need the dynamic passing of values - if you can pass in the field names "statically", you've already got a working solution.